# Crash with getAdviceList

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm trying to get advice list from my route that i created from trackElement, but when i call the function SKRouteManager.getInstance().getAdviceList(SKDistanceUnitType.DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER_METERS ) the application crash. I also calculateRoute with the function calculateRoute() but the app crash yet.
I call these function in onRouteCalculationCompleted() like the example give by skobbler

Comment: When calculating the route are you also rendering it? See: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/6523-Getting-crash-on-statement-routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat for some known issues

Comment: I add route.setRouteExposed(true). But the app crash yet.It may be a bug of the framework 2.3.0 ?

Comment: Could you include the complete snippet of settings you are using when calling the route calculation?